# preg_replace style attr in $content and Editing post_content before saving

Tags: content, save-post, regex, post-content, customization

I`am trying to clean style attr from tags when saving posts and products but nothing happend.
(I checked my regexp on https://regex101.com/)

```
function filter_style_save($content) {
$re = '/(<[^>]+)(style=".*?")/';
$replace = "$1";
$content1 = preg_replace($re, $replace, $content);
$content = $content1;
return $content;
};
add_filter('content_save_pre', 'filter_style_save', 99, 2);
```

UPD. I have updated regex to match success result on regex101

```
    (<[^>]+)(style=".*?")
```

I expect that attribute STYLE will be deleted with all its content:

```
<ul>
<li style="padding: 5px 0;">Wooden part</li>
<li class="red" style="padding: 5px 0;">Metall top plate</li>
<li style="padding: 5px 0;">Metall front logo</li>
</ul>
//Should be like this
<ul>
<li >Wooden part</li>
<li class="red">Metall top plate</li>
<li >Metall front logo</li>
</ul>
```

**UPD 2. I stoped at using filter `wp_insert_post_data`.**

```
function filter_style_save1($data, $postarr) {
$content = $data['post_content'];

$re = '/(<[^>]+)(style=".*?")/';
$replace = "$1";
$content = preg_replace($re, $replace, $content);

$data['post_content'] = $content;
//error_log( print_r(  $data['post_content'], true ) );
return $data;
};
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'filter_style_save1', 10, 2);
```

Error log shows the right content, but post_content wasn't replaced.

**UPD 3.** Also I have noticed that when I duplicate the post - error log shows `<li style="padding: 5px 0;">Metall front logo</li>` and when  I update existing post, it shows `<li style=\"padding: 5px 0;\">Metall front logo</li>` with slashes. Maybe this cause the problem with regex. But why they appear I don't understand.

Comment: You haven't explained how your regex should work. Please provide possible inputs and the expected output.

Comment: Also - are you checking content that's already been created? The `content_save_pre` filter works on new content, but will not fix old content.

Comment: @WebElaine I tried to add `$content .= 'text ' . $content; return $content;`  and these changes were saved. But you right, when I clone this post, it was filtered. What filter can you recommend? I tried action `save_post` but can't to replace `post_content` with my content. Is it right choice?

Comment: I also tried `wp_insert_post_data` but also can't replace the content.

Comment: A filter on `the_content` is probably what you need. Unless you go back and clean out the previously saved data, you're stuck filtering the content that is already saved. https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content

Comment: IN this situation `the_content` is not fitted because I have gallery, which write it's code in style attr. And I striped this code out too. And actually I want to have clean code in my posts. It is easier to edit posts without any style garbage.

Comment: 100% agree with you that it's better to have clean data saved, instead of filtering it after. So, your solution will have 2 parts: 1. update the data in the database. You should be able to work out a MySQL regex query that gets rid of the already-saved inline styles. Part 2. Set up a filter on a different hook - try `wp_insert_post_data`, it runs between the time the user clicks "publish/update" and the time when the content is actually saved to the database. You may have run into problems with that hook initially because there's both `post_content` and `post_content_filtered`.